# .each() find the last item and create an if statement

Tags: jquery

I've got the following jQuery,

```
function animTweets($tweets) {
    $tweets.each(function () {
        var $tweet = $(this);
        $('#twitterTile').queue('myQueue', function (next) {
            $tweet.animate({top: 0, height: 'show'},
                        {duration: 300,
                         queue: false,
                         complete: next
                        });
        }).delay(1E10, 'myQueue');
    });
}
```

It iterates through items contained in a list ($tweets).

How can I create an `if` statement so that the last item has a different animation?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total number of tweets using `.length` and then check against it using the `index` that `.each()` exposes to check if the current `index` is the last one:

```
function animTweets($tweets) {
    var total = $tweets.length;
    $tweets.each(function (index, obj) {
        var $tweet = $(this);
        if ((index + 1) == total) {
            //this is the last one
        } else {
            $('#twitterTile').queue('myQueue', function (next) {
                $tweet.animate({top: 0, height: 'show'},
                            {duration: 300,
                             queue: false,
                             complete: next
                            });
            }).delay(1E10, 'myQueue');
        }
    });
}
```

Docs for `.each()`: http://api.jquery.com/each

Comment: @ZacharyBurt Good catch, `index` starts at zero and `.length` starts at one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tweets.each(function (index) {
    if(index == $tweets.length-1) {
    //special behavior
    }
});
```

Comment: Might as well cache the value of `$tweets.length` since it will probably be used more than once.

Answer (score 0):

```
function animTweets($tweets) {
    var len =  $tweets.length;
    var count = 1;
    $tweets.each(function () {
        var $tweet = $(this);
        if(len  == count ){
           //different anim
        }else{
          $('#twitterTile').queue('myQueue', function (next) {
             $tweet.animate({top: 0, height: 'show'},
                        {duration: 300,
                         queue: false,
                         complete: next
                        });
          }).delay(1E10, 'myQueue');
        }
        count++;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`.slice()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [`.last()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/last/):

```
$tweets.slice(0, -1).each(...);
var $lastTweet = $tweets.last();
// do something with the last tweet.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we forget that `.each()` isn't always better than a good-old fashioned `for` loop because we lose control over the iteration.  Assuming that the argument to animTweets is jQuery object, you can use a `for` loop like this:

```
function animTweets($tweets) {
    var $tweet;
    for (var i = 0, len = $tweets.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
        $tweet = $tweets.eq(i);
        $('#twitterTile').queue('myQueue', function (next) {
            $tweet.animate({top: 0, height: 'show'},
                        {duration: 300,
                         queue: false,
                         complete: next
                        });
        }).delay(1E10, 'myQueue');
    }
    // now process the last one separately
    tweet$ = $tweets.eq(-1);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `$tweet = $tweets.eq(i);` is a bit cleaner than `$tweet = $(tweets[i]);` IMO.

Comment: I said that I assumed tweets was an array of elements.  It doesn't say in their question what exactly it is.  If it's a jQuery object with elements inside it, then I'd agree with your suggestion.

Comment: Oh sorry, I only skimmed over the text ;) But if `$tweets` was a normal array, `$tweets.each` would throw an error.

Comment: @FelixKling - right you are.  I guess it must be a jQuery object.  I'll change to `.eq(i)`.